# Confused about display:inline and float:left

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have two elements:

```
<span class="b">This is inline element</span>
<div class="a"></div>

.a {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background: red;
   float: left;
}
```

The `span` element is after the float element：[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YVW6Y/1/)

But I think the inline element is in standard flow, so it's position shouldn't 
be effected by the float element? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spec may clear this up for you](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats ... unless the box establishes a new block formatting context

As for inline elements

> In general, the left edge of a line box touches the left edge of its containing block and the right edge touches the right edge of its containing block. However, floating boxes may come between the containing block edge and the line box edge. Thus, although line boxes in the same inline formatting context generally have the same width (that of the containing block), they may vary in width if available horizontal space is reduced due to floats

There is [also a section devoted to "next to floats."](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float)

Essentially block-level elements create a new block context that pushes the float down to the next line.  `inline` elements do not create a new block context so the float can exist on the same line.  Note that this is only the case if there is room for both elements: http://jsfiddle.net/YVW6Y/3/

Answer (score 0):

Inline formatting is what text normally gets. It means, informally, that things are filled into lines.

A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current line. The most interesting characteristic of a float is that content may flow along its side.

So a float is a sort of third category of formatting model. It relates to inline as being, informally put, a layout model.